# Collected Gravitational Field

Tags: gravity, field-theory

I wasn't sure what to call this, I'm not a physicist. I basically have a collection of massive bodies. I to calculate the gravitational field of all those objects collected; how to do this?

The reason I want to do this is because at the end I want to see how another object will interact with that collection objects, and it'll be a lot of work to calculate how it's influenced by every single body in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

To find the total force, you can simply add up all the contributions of all bodies.

Depending on the distribution or initial/boundary conditions of the bodies, there may be clever tricks to make it easier.

If you want to calculate (for example) the orbit of an object in a three+ body problem, you'll have to resort to either approximations or compute it numerically - the three body problem cannot be (at any rate, it *hasn't* been) solved analytically.

Comment: That'd still require me to calculate how every object influences that one specific object outside the collection, and wouldn't simplify the problem at all.

Comment: There's no way to reduce the complexity of the calculation unless you give more details on the problem.

Comment: @JeroenBollen: How many massive objects are there? Thousands? Millions? I don't have too much experience with this, but if there's less than a few thousand then it shouldn't be much of a problem to just add them all up in real time.

Comment: The thing is, there will be multiple objects outside the collection I will have to calculate for how they are influenced by the collection. Because the collection is that big it'd be a pain to do it for every single object in the collection every single time.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus It'd be around a few thousand inside the collection, but there'd also be a few hundred outside the collection.

Comment: I don't have experience with this, but I know that for large scale gravitational interaction simulations, the fast multipole method is used to reduce the computational complexity from $O(n^2)$ to $O(n\log(n))$. See http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/N-body_simulations_(gravitational) and check out the fast multipole section.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Why would Frederic Brünner's answer be incorrect? It looks pretty much like what I was looking for. I don't see a direct need for another 'algorithm'.

Comment: @JeroenBollen: Frederic's answer is an approximation. It is valid if your test object is very far away from the collection of thousands of objects which are attracting your test object. However, once the test object gets close to the collection of thousands of objects, it will become inaccurate. So it may be viable, but it'll depend on what you're trying to simulate.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus What would make the calculation inaccurate? I am calculating in 2D space if that matters.

Comment: @JeroenBollen: As I mentioned, it's an approximation (in both 3D and 2D). It will always give an incorrect answer, but depending on the configuration in question it may be close enough to the correct answer to be usable, and if so, it will vastly reduce the computation requirements.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus If the fast multipole method is really considerably more accurate could you post up a possible implementation as an answer?

Comment: @JeroenBollen: I've never written one so I'm sort of useless, but perhaps you can ask the people at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/? They will almost certainly have people with experience writing these sort of things. Also, user Chris White works in astrophysics and presumably has some experience with writing this sort of stuff, and he answered a similar problem at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3566/what-is-the-correct-way-of-integrating-in-astronomy-simulations/3568#3568 so I'd recommend asking him (he sometimes is in chat).

Comment: That said, for that question the main concern was long-term accuracy of the evolution (for which symplectic methods are supposedly best) and not computational speed, so you may have to ask Chris separately about what the fastest way to go about this, provided that speed is more of a concern than accuracy for your case.